# Clustering Points in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I have done to create people distribution map including its photo as icon. And now, I want to try clustering them. But, I confused to implement them if reffering to Mapbox Docs (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/), because I looping the point to show each photo of the point. Do someone have an idea to this topic? This my code:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    //YOUR TURN: Replace with csv export link
    url: `${google_sheet_name}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=${sheet_name}`,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (csvData) {
        makeGeoJSON(csvData);
    }
});

let makeGeoJSON = csvData => {
    csv2geojson.csv2geojson(csvData, {
        latfield: 'latitude',
        lonfield: 'longitude',
        delimiter: ','
    }, (err, data) => {
        var geo = {
            'id': 'csvData',
            'type': 'circle',
            'source': {
                'type': 'geojson',
                'data': data
            },
        }

        geo.source.data.features.forEach(marker => {
            var el = document.createElement('img');
            el.className = 'icon-image';
            el.src = marker.properties.image_path

            // make a marker for each feature and add it to the map
            new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
                .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
                .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
                .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.name + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
                .addTo(map)
        })

        let UseBbox = () => {
            let bbox = turf.bbox(data);
            map.fitBounds(bbox, {
                padding: 50
            })
        }
        UseBbox()
    });
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering marker for each point, the example works with geojson data and layers. This gives better performance when you have more number of points.
The basic flow for your case would be something like

- Add data to source to map as explained in example
- Add 2 layers, one for rendering cluster icon, another for uncluster point
- Clustered icon can be same as in example
- Unclustered layer can use imagepath to render the user image

To dynamically load and render image use styleimagemissing event. Refer the example at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image-missing-generated/

Note that adding images should be done [synchronosly](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/8335#issuecomment-505075417)